# Proper way to encode apostrophe/single quote in place search

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm not finding the magic encoding for searching the Facebook place database for a name with an apostrophe in it.

These don't work

```
search?q=Duke's Restaurant & Barefoot Bar&type=place&center=21.2766380277,-157.8278034925&distance=1000

search?q=Duke%27s Restaurant & Barefoot Bar&type=place&center=21.2766380277,-157.8278034925&distance=1000

search?q=Duke\u0027s Restaurant & Barefoot Bar&type=place&center=21.2766380277,-157.8278034925&distance=1000
```

I can strip the apostrophe and it works:

```
search?q=Dukes Restaurant & Barefoot Bar&type=place&center=21.2766380277,-157.8278034925&distance=1000
```

Is there a way for Facebook to recognize the apostrophe correctly, or is their recommendation to just strip them?  I can't find anything to that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `Duke\'s Restaurant` ?

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  Tried it, but no luck.

Comment: `Duke&#039;s Restaurant` <-- have found this a couple places as a possible solution, including the link above.